# Pylance does not show docstring for local import in VSCode Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

I am working on a Jupyter notebook on VSCod. when I import functions that I have in another local folder, VSCode does not show the docstring of the function. When I hover on the file name in the notebook, I see the message Import "scripts" could not be resolved - Pylance.

It works correctly with libraries like Numpy and Pandas and if I defined the function on the same notebook. It also works perfectly with python `.py` files.

Code to reproduce where the file scripts is in some/path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("some/path")
from scripts import func1
```

This is my settings.json file

```
{
    "gitlens.defaultDateFormat": null,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./tools"
    ],
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "yaml": true,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

This should have been solved by this issue [#3017](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3017)

## Old answer

After hours of searching, here is the solution per [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3017#issuecomment-1180886636). Just disable the Pylance LSP Notebooks experiment by adding the following to the `settings.json` file for user:

```
"python.pylanceLspNotebooksEnabled": false
```

and this in the workspace `settings.json` file just to include your local module.

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "path/to/local/module"
]
```

If you use the same local path frequently in your project and you are using a conda environment, there is a better way to solve this issue. Plus, avoiding adding the lines `sys.path.append(..)`. You can run the command `conda develop path/to/local/module` and it will add this path to the libraries of this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble but the solution proposed does not work completely for me... It shows only

`(function) siges_seine: ((mailleId: int) -> DataFrame) | Any``

but not the docstring I have written.

Comment: I think it is better if you add more details about your settings, but you can make sure all your extensions are updated

Comment: This might be better posted as a comment on the proposed solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).